# How can I find integers in an array of strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to print the items (strings) of an array in order. The order is the strings that contain the smallest numbers will be printed first, etc.

I want to use a max number variable for the largest integer in the arrays strings but I'm not sure how to.

Pseudocode:

```
array = ['Tom 7','Thomas 3','Toby 2','Dominic 4','Henry 7']

maxnumber = #largest integer in the arrays strings

for i in array:

 for n in in range(0,maxnumber)

      if n in array[i]:

           print(array[i])
```

Comment: Are your inputs always going to be of the form `"word number"`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sorted` with a `lambda` function to sort your items based on the value of the number within each item

```
>>> array = ['Tom 7','Thomas 3','Toby 2','Dominic 4','Henry 7']
>>> ordered = sorted(array, key=lambda i: int(i.split()[1]))
>>> ordered
['Toby 2', 'Thomas 3', 'Dominic 4', 'Tom 7', 'Henry 7']
```

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers can appear anywhere in the string you can use regex to find them.

```
import re
array = ['Tom 7','Thomas 3','Toby 2','Dominic 4','Henry 7']
for i in sorted(array, key=lambda s: int(re.findall(r'\d+', s)[0])):
    print(i)
```

This outputs:

```
Toby 2
Thomas 3
Dominic 4
Tom 7
Henry 7
```